# .NET 7 Microsoft.Data.SqlClient PlatformNotSupportedException error on DbContext use

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0, sqlclient

I have migrated my class library project from .NET Framework 4.8 to .NET 7 using the upgrade assistant. My SQL Server database is in the cloud. I am working on Windows 10 OS and with Visual Studio 2022.

When I try to use the DbContext I get this error:

> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform.'

PackageReferences are listed below (using NuGet to add them to the project):

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="5.1.5" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.runtime" Version="5.1.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.15" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions" Version="7.0.15" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="7.0.15">
    <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
  </PackageReference>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="7.0.15" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.15" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.6" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="7.0.15">
    <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
  </PackageReference>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="8.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.SqlServer.Server" Version="1.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="PreEmptive.Protection.Checks.Attributes" Version="2.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="System.Data.Common" Version="4.3.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.6" />
  <PackageReference Include="System.Interactive.Async" Version="6.0.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="System.Memory" Version="4.5.5" />
  <PackageReference Include="System.Reflection.Emit" Version="4.7.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="System.Reflection.TypeExtensions" Version="4.7.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.Handles" Version="4.3.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces" Version="8.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" Version="4.7.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions" Version="8.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory" Version="8.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="8.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="8.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="8.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" Version="8.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" Version="8.0.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives" Version="8.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms" Version="7.0.4" />
  <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
  <PackageReference Include="System.Collections.Immutable" Version="8.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="System.ComponentModel.Composition" Version="8.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="8.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="System.Data.OleDb" Version="8.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" Version="8.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="System.Management" Version="8.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" Version="6.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="System.Security.Cryptography.Cng" Version="5.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs" Version="8.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="System.Security.Cryptography.Xml" Version="7.0.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

DbContext code looks like this:

```
public partial class dbContext : DbContext
{
    public dbContext()
        : base(new DbContextOptionsBuilder<dbContext>().UseSqlServer("Data Source=SERVER_IP;Initial Catalog=MY_DB_NAME;User Id=USER_NAME;Password=MY_PW;").Options)
    {
    }
}
```

I have tried to downgrade dependencies but it didn't work.

I've also tried to specify runtime in the `.csproj` file like below, but that also did not work:

```
<RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
<RuntimeIdentifier>win</RuntimeIdentifier>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="$(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.data.sqlclient\5.1.5\runtimes\win\lib\net6.0\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="CopyToBin" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.data.sqlclient\5.1.5\runtimes\win\lib\net6.0\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)\bin" />
  </Target>
```

I have also cleared the nuget cache but it didn't help. I guess I am in problem with package versions but not sure which versions to use. All of them seems to be the latest versions.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/download-microsoft-sqlclient-data-provider?view=sql-server-ver16  Also make sure you do a clean build.

Comment: SQL Server has no problems with .NET 7. Keep in mind that .NET 7 is .NET *Core* 7. Everything is different, including `csproj`. There's *no reason* to copy DLLs manually. The correct ones are installed from NuGet and copied to the output folder during build. In fact, that's probably what *causes* the problem. I'd suggest creating a *new* Console project, adding EF Core and trying to implement the [EF Core Quickstart example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=netcore-cli) to see how things actually work

Comment: Your `csproj` contains a lot of unnecessary packages too that were left over from the .NET Framework project `Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces` is certainly not needed. Almost all of the `System.` packages aren't needed, they existed only to enable the use of .NET Standard 2.0 packages. All of these are included in the .NET runtime itself now. Once you create the Console project check what packages are actually installed

Comment: The .csproj still seems to be referencing the legacy `System.Data.SqlClient` package. Have you tried to move all of its code references to `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` and remove the old package reference?

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisKanavos, thank you for your suggestions, I am inspecting the dependency difference between core and framework projects. Removed the Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces but the error persists. Our licensing system uses Cryptography dependencies but not sure about other ones that start with System.

Comment: Removing System.Data.SqlClient and changing code references didn't help @AlwaysLearning, But it was one of the unnecessary dependencies. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

**Brute force approach (that works)**

I have found that sometimes adding Microsoft.Data.SqlClient to all the projects involved (even if it doesn't seem like they would need them) solves the problem. Then once everything compiles, you can go in and try removing them one at time and recompiling until only the ones you need remain.